# Jquery mobile requirejs init events randomly not fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is very strange. It seems as if those pageinit events don't get fired all the time. When I refresh the page they don't get fired anymore until after a big of time (or maybe also randomly).

Is there some caching? Is it maybe an issue with ... I don't know what (I guess that's why I'm asking the question here)?

As you can see I'm using requirejs to structure my code. Again, the actual code I guess is fine, it's really just that it doesn't behave the same every time.

```
define(["jquery", "jquery-mobile", "app/RestaurantCollection"], function($, jqm, restaurantCollection) {

/**
 * Init all the event handlers that need to be present on the overview page
 * @return {[type]} [description]
 */
function initOverview() {

    console.log("init overview as function")

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#restaurant", function(event) {
        console.log("init detail")
    });

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#page-overview", function(event) {
        console.log("init overview")
        restaurantCollection.init();
    });

}

return {
    initOverview: initOverview
}
});
```

Comment: Do you initialize app after including JQM or before?

Comment: I would assume before JQM.

Comment: Pageinit is a JQM event not jquery. Place it after JQM.

Comment: understand, it is loading... I added jquery mobile explicitely to the define statement

Comment: So you got it working?

Comment: nope, but I found more issues, and I'm not really sure anymore whether I should take the jqm route. It seems that mobileinit is firing right after jquery mobile is loaded, but since I'm using requirejs most likely that's before the rest has been loaded, so having to keep an order... um... I don't know.